# Add Padding top in a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my linear layout:

It is too close to the top. I am trying to add some space to the top. I have tried using `android:paddingTop` but that does not work. How do I add space at top in linear layout?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="200dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pDescriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pTypeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pPriceTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pQuantityTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you show in your image, it looks likely that you've already specified `android:padding` to give padding to all four edges. If that is the case, adding `android:paddingTop` won't do anything; the system will ignore that attribute in favor of the generic `android:padding`.

If, for example, you currently have `android:padding="16dp"`, you'll have to delete that and replace it with something like this:

```
android:paddingTop="32dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
```

---

If you are using `ListView` and want to add only some spacing above the very first item, then the situation is different. Instead of adding `paddingTop` to your item view, you have some choices.

#### Padding on the `ListView`

Add these two attributes to your `ListView` or `RecyclerView` tag:

```
android:paddingTop="32dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

This is by far the easiest solution, but it will affect how the scrollbar is drawn, which you may not like.

#### Add a header view to the `ListView`

Create a layout file for a header view. I suggest using a `<Space>` tag if you just want some extra space at top:

```
<Space
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"/>
```

Then inflate this and add it to your `ListView`:

```
val header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, listView, false)
listView.addHeaderView(header)
```

By default, a divider will still appear between this header and your first list item. If you don't want that, you can disable it:

```
listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(false)
```

#### Dynamic padding in `getView()`

In your adapter's `getView()` method, you can programmatically set the padding based on the item's `position`. First, define two `dimen` resources like this:

```
<dimen name="extra_padding">32dp</dimen>
<dimen name="normal_padding">16dp</dimen>
```

Then, in `getView()`, add code like this:

```
val paddingTop = when (position) {
    0 -> resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.extra_padding)
    else -> resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.normal_padding)
}

view.setPadding(view.paddingLeft, paddingTop, view.paddingRight, view.paddingBottom)
```

Comment: so that worked, added a padding top. But it adds padding top to each individual item though. How do I just add the padding top to the Layout only, not the items that it contains?

Comment: Could you add to your question both the xml source code for your layout and a picture of what it looks like now?

Comment: Are you using `ListView` or `RecyclerView` here? It looks like you're repeating the same `LinearLayout` + five `TextView` "widget" over and over.

Comment: ListView. I have five different fields so I used five TextViews.